# Can I prevent awk from adding extra line break in the end of the file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file to process

```
public class Controller {
    public class Model{
        public void init() {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String y;
}
```

and a script to process this file

```
class=force-app/main/default/classes/Controller.cls
echo $class
awk '\
{
    print;
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

However, this script is adding one more extra linebreak in the end of the file after processing which I want to avoid and prevent.

so instead of just copying the file,
it adds one more new line in the end of the file

```
public class Controller {
    public class Model{
        public void init() {
            for ... {
                if ... {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled public String y;
}
// Unnecessary line break here which is why file is flagged in source control system as modified while there was only line break change
```

I have seen someone was suggesting to print previous line and check if $NR is bigger than 1, I have tried to adopt that solution but it doesn't work and instead produces an empty file.

```
class=force-app/main/default/classes/Controller.cls
 
echo $class
awk '\
{
    if ($NR > 1) {
        print x;
    }
    x = $0
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

Also I tried to use `getline` function but it doesn't work either

```
class=force-app/main/default/classes/TasksController.cls
 
echo $class
awk '\
{
    if (getline <= 0) {
        printf;
    } else {
        print;
    }
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

Is this possible to make it work so that new line is not appended to the end of the processed file?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253459/discussion-on-question-by-patlatus-can-i-prevent-awk-from-adding-extra-line-brea); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Given these input files (`PS1:` is just my prompt):

```
PS1: cat -e foo
public class Controller {$
    public class Model{$
        public void init() {$
            for ... {$
                if ... {$
                }$
            }$
        }$
    }$
    $
    @AuraEnabled public String y;$
}$
PS1:
```

```
PS1: cat -e bar
public class Controller {$
    public class Model{$
        public void init() {$
            for ... {$
                if ... {$
                }$
            }$
        }$
    }$
    $
    @AuraEnabled public String y;$
}PS1:
```

Note that my PS1 prompt `PS1:` appears on the same line as the final `}` in `bar` because that file does not have a terminating newline while `foo` does.

Run this tool which uses any version of any variant of awk:

```
PS1: cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for class in "$@"; do
    { cat "$class"; printf '\n'; } |
    awk '
        {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $0
            sep = ORS
        }
    ' > "$class.copy"
done
PS1:
```

```
PS1: ./tst.sh
PS1:
```

which produces this output:

```
PS1: cat -e foo.copy
public class Controller {$
    public class Model{$
        public void init() {$
            for ... {$
                if ... {$
                }$
            }$
        }$
    }$
    $
    @AuraEnabled public String y;$
}$
PS1:
```

```
PS1: cat -e bar.copy
public class Controller {$
    public class Model{$
        public void init() {$
            for ... {$
                if ... {$
                }$
            }$
        }$
    }$
    $
    @AuraEnabled public String y;$
}PS1:
```

which is identical to the input, including retaining the final newline if it was present in the input.

The above works by first adding a newline before piping the input to awk and then ignoring that added newline when producing output. This ensures that not only does awk see a valid text file for input, but it reproduces the original file in the output.

Maybe this will help clarify what the above is doing:

```
PS1: printf 'stuff\n' | cat -e
stuff$
PS1: 

PS1: printf 'stuff' | cat -e
stuffPS1:

PS1: { printf 'stuff\n'; printf '\n'; } | cat -e
stuff$
$
PS1:

PS1: { printf 'stuff'; printf '\n'; } | cat -e
stuff$
PS1:

PS1: { printf 'stuff\n'; printf '\n'; } | awk '{printf "<%s>%s", sep, $0; sep=ORS}' | cat -e
<>stuff<$
>PS1:

PS1: { printf 'stuff'; printf '\n'; } | awk '{printf "<%s>%s", sep, $0; sep=ORS}' | cat -e
<>stuffPS1:
```

So it's adding a newline to the end of the input then piping the result to awk, then awk is never printing a newline at the end of a line but instead printing a newline at the start of the 2nd and subsequent lines.

So for an originally valid text file awk sees:

```
stuff\n\n
```

while for an originally invalid text file awk sees:

```
stuff\n
```

both of which are now valid text files as the input ends with `\n` in both cases, and when awk handles the first one (which is now 2 lines of input) it processes it as:

```
<sep is ""><$0 is "stuff">
<sep is "\n"><$0 is "">
```

which outputs the same as the original first input:

```
stuff\n
```

and when it handles the second one (which is 1 line of input) it processes:

```
<sep is ""><$0 is "stuff">
```

which outputs the same as the original second input:

```
stuff
```

Comment: how do you get here `ignoring that added newline when producing output`? I don't really follow

Comment: is `sep == ''` by default if undefined? and then you just join lines using ORS, which is by default the newline, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Essentially yes, when used in the context of a string (as I'm using it) an undefined variable like `sep` will have the same value as `""`. I added some more explanation to my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want a lagged row printing utility to avoid final `\n`, then this should work :

```
jot -w 'ABC%d' 9 |

mawk '
END { 
     printf("END { } section printf for last row:: { %s }", __) 

} { print " | NR :: "(NR)" | input :: \""($_) "\" |" \
                          " output :: \""(__) "\"" > "/dev/stderr" 

} ($!NF = __ substr(_,__ = $_))^(NR == !_)'
```

---

- `/dev/stderr`

  ```
  | NR :: 1 | input :: "ABC1" | output :: ""
  | NR :: 2 | input :: "ABC2" | output :: "ABC1"
  | NR :: 3 | input :: "ABC3" | output :: "ABC2"
  | NR :: 4 | input :: "ABC4" | output :: "ABC3"
  | NR :: 5 | input :: "ABC5" | output :: "ABC4"
  | NR :: 6 | input :: "ABC6" | output :: "ABC5"
  | NR :: 7 | input :: "ABC7" | output :: "ABC6"
  | NR :: 8 | input :: "ABC8" | output :: "ABC7"
  | NR :: 9 | input :: "ABC9" | output :: "ABC8"
  ```

---

- `/dev/stdout`

  ```
     1  ABC1
     2  ABC2
     3  ABC3
     4  ABC4
     5  ABC5
     6  ABC6
     7  ABC7
     8  ABC8
     9  END { } section printf for last row:: { ABC9 }%
  ```

---

without all the debugging messages, then it's just

> ```
> gawk 'END { printf("{%s}", __) }
>       ($!NF = __ substr(_, __ = $_))^(NR == !_)'
> ```

---

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
ABC5
ABC6
ABC7
ABC8
{ABC9}%
```

> *The special `substr(…)` construct is for in-place swapping (of any number or string, even if the 2 targets have different types)*

===============

but if your input is known to be not too gigantic (e.g. `< 512 MB`), then might as well do it all in one shot :

```
jot -w 'ABC%d' 9 |
```

---

> ```
> mawk $$ ORS= RS='[\n\r]*$'
> ```

---

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
ABC5
ABC6
ABC7
ABC8
ABC9%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I was using the wrong name for the variable, it should be `NR` and not `$NR`.

Now looks like this version works fine and doesn't add unnecessary line break in the end of the file

```
class=force-app/main/default/classes/Controller.cls
 
echo $class
awk '\
{    
    if (NR > 1) {
        print x;
    }
    x = $0
}
END {
    printf x
}' $class > $class.copy
mv $class.copy $class
```

Comment: FYI: A dollar in front of a name refers to the field number. `$4` is the content of the 4th field of the current record, and if you do `X=4`, then `$X` is also  the 4th field.

Comment: yes, I confused that with bash/sh general syntax which require $ before the variable name to access its value

Comment: now it brings the opposite problem. If there were a line break in the end of file, it is no longer copied. How can I use awk in the way presence/absense of final line break is kept when copying/processing by awk?

Comment: I find your END-block confusing. Why `printf`? If `x` contains a _format specification_, I would expect a matching expression list for this format. If `x` does _not_ contain a format specification, why then doing a `printf`, unless you **want** to suppress the final newline. Perhaps simply replacing `printf` by `print` would solve the issue then?

Comment: Never do `printf $anything`, always `printf "%s", $anything` instead as the former will fail when `$anything` contains printf formatting characters such as `%s`.

Comment: Your current code would **remove** the required terminating newline from your input if one was present thereby changing a valid text file into an invalid one and so YMMV with what any subsequent text-processing tool might do with it. Don't do that.

Comment: Regarding "How can I use awk in the way presence/absense of final line break is kept when copying/processing by awk?" - that's possible with GNU awk (and there's a workaround with other awks+shell) but that's asking how to leave a broken input file broken instead of fixing it so we need to understand why you'd want to do such a thing.